# Можно ли работать с изображением через Vulkan (API)?

Tags: c++, python, python-3.x, vulkan

Хочу писать программы анализирующие фото и видео в реальном времени, основной язык питон 3(через 2 мес начну изучать С++), какие библиотеки лучше использовать PIL или Vulkan (API)(для изменения фото), в дальнейшем планирую расширение программ до игрового движка, интересуют свободные проги, библиотеки, и кросплатформенность. Все это планирую делать несколько лет как хобби, т.к. я не специалист а языки учу по книгам. Какие библиотеки посоветуете? п.с. разумеется лет через 15 планируется сделать что-нибуть на основе для продажи.
Сорри если что не так спросил

Comment: PIL, Vulcan не кроссплатформен и не работает с устройствами без поддержки Vulcan, например встроеные чипы intel, и даже некоторые NVidia.

Comment: @ishidex2 Vulcan как раз вполне кроссплатформенный, однако проблема в том, что на релевантных платформах он не нужен, так как там уже есть DirectX / metal. Ну и конечно начав изучать C++ через два месяца с Vulcan можно будет работать года этак через два-три.